# How to override django signup view class

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-class-based-views

I want to override django all-auth signup view to input an extra field value.

In this case, User model has a foreign field which is combined to Company model.

```
from allauth.account.views import SignupView as AllAuthSignupView
from .models import Company

class SignupView(AllAuthSignupView):
    def save(self):
        user = super(SignupView, self).save()
        a_company = get_object_or_404(Company, name='A')
        user.company = a_company

        return user
```

However, This only saves username, password, email. The company field is NULL.
I don't want an answer that recommends change the default value in Company model. That's not the way I try to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you try adding `user.save()` after the line `user.company = a_company`?

Comment: @Sanip It doesn't work. It seems like I tried totally wrong way. Because Class-based-view doesn't have save method...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than overriding the view, you can simply create a new Form to save the additional data. For example:

```
companies = (
    ('comapny_name_1', 'ABC'),
    ('comapny_name_2', 'DEF'),
)


class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    company = forms.ChoiceField(choices=companies)

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.company = Company.objects.get(name=self.cleaned_data['company'])
        user.save()
```

Then add the Form Path to  `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS` in `settings.py`:

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'path.to.SignupForm'
```

More information can be found in [documentation](https://docs.allauth.org/en/latest/account/configuration.html).

Comment: If it'd rather to override Form than View, I have to override SignupForm of django-allauth.

Comment: No, you don't have to. You need to create a new form and add a method `def signup(self, request, user)` and add changes there(same as the given code in the answer)